# Grid of independent buttons with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am studying ReactJS and I'm trying to build grid of buttons that can be selected / deselected individually and once I press a submit button I can collect pressed buttons. How should I build this in ReactJS way? All the buttons should have same size.

A bonus question: How can I use 'press and hold' event to select multiple buttons while moving mouse over them?

App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
    
    import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
    import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
    
    const Item = styled(ToggleButton)(({ theme }) => ({
      ...theme.typography.body2,
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
      textTransform: 'none',
    }));
    
    const NUMBERS = [
      ['1', '2', '3'], 
      ['4', '5', '6'], 
      ['7', '8', '9'], 
    ];
    
    class Choices {
      constructor() {
        this.selected = new Map();
      }
    
      choose(hand, newState) {
        this.selected[hand] = newState;
      }
    }
    
    
    function App() {
      const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);
      let userChoices = new Choices();
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Grid container spacing={0} width={850}>
              {NUMBERS.map((row, index) => (
                row.map((value, colIndex) => (
                  <Grid item key={index} key={value}>
                    <ToggleButton value={value} selected={selected} onChange={() => { 
                      setSelected(!selected);
                      userChoices.choose({value}, selected);
                      }}>
                      {value}
                    </ToggleButton>
                  </Grid>
                ))
              ))}       
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );

    reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage the selected state in an array of button objects:

```
const [buttonValues, setButtonValues] = useState([
      [{value: '1', isSelected: false}, {value: '2', isSelected: false}, {value: '3', isSelected: false}], 
      [...], 
      [...], 
    ]);
```

This way, you can toggle each button individually, and update the state array to the current toggled value.